# Google Maps API v3 - Smooth google map animation from one location to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API for the first time and I'm wondering how I can get a smooth zoom in animation with it.

For some of the locations I don't get an animation effect. 
Below is my code:

```
function show_map_animation(type){

    switch(type){
        case 1:
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.88993514401056, 16.962821180560002);
            var zoom_level = 3;
        break;

        case 2:
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.0730555556, -100.546666667);
            var zoom_level = 2;
        break;

        case 3:
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.760271554918987, -58.361263562499985);
            var zoom_level = 3;
        break;


        case 4:
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.08751187316051, 89.29666666670002);
            var zoom_level = 2;
        break;

        case 5:
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.9212400652153145, 21.97890625000002);
            var zoom_level = 3;
        break;

        default:
             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.00, 10.00);
             var zoom_level = 2;
        break;
    }

    google_map.map.setCenter(latlng);
    google_map.map.setZoom(zoom_level);


}
```

FYI I click this function onclick of a button.

Comment: You can try with `panTo(latLng)` instead of `setCenter(latlng);`. From docs: _Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated._

Comment: @AntoJurković I tried but the problem still persists. Its mainly when I change from case 1 to 3 or 5. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to do it in a loop with changing zoom level by 1? Not sure but jump from 1 to for example 5 could be problem.

Comment: I am sorry but did not get this approach. If its not much of a problem, can you please write an answer to help me out here. Thanks

Comment: What I meant is to zoom in/out in steps like: `var currentZoom,
    timeStep = 150;

var numOfSteps = Math.abs(zoom_level - currentZoom);
var step = (zoom_level > currentZoom) ? 1 : -1;

for (var i = 0; i < numOfSteps; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        currentZoom += step;
    
        map.setZoom(currentZoom);
    }, (i + 1)*timeStep);
}
`. You can try different `timeStep` values to see if you get any better result. I am not sure if this is solution for you at all.

Comment: panTo will not work for distant cases: in documentation it says: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference
: 
"If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated."